# Is there a simple way to do the following transformation of multiple dataframes?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, transformation

I have three data frames that I want to merge into a single one, keeping only the overlapping timestamps while inserting 1 into column values where all the three tables converge on 1. Otherwise, I should report NAN on the non-converging cells.

Please see the pic.

I tried my best using 'merge' but could not figure it out.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [None, 1, None], 'C2': [1, None, 1]}, index=[0, 1, 4])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [None, 1,1, None], 'C2': [1, None, 1,1]}, index=[0, 1,2, 4])
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C1': [1,1, None,1], 'C2': [None, None, 1,None]}, index=[1, 2,3, 4])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a simple way achieving this. One problem is, that you already have NaNs in your data that you cannot distinguish from "missing indices". In your specific example you can address this issue by replacing NaNs with zeros. Than it is straight forward, i. e. kind of:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3]

# replace nan with 0
for df in dfs:
    df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
       
# concat first column of all dfs
c1 = pd.concat([df['C1'] for df in dfs], axis=1)
# drop indices not present in all dfs
c1 = c1.dropna()
# find indices with only 1's
c1 = (c1 == 1).all(axis=1)

# concat second column of all dfs
c2 = pd.concat([df['C2'] for df in dfs], axis=1)
# drop indices not present in all dfs
c2 = c2.dropna()
# find indices with only 1's
c2 = (c2 == 1).all(axis=1)

res = pd.concat([c1.rename('C1'), c2.rename('C2')], axis=1)
res = res.replace({True: 1, False: np.NaN})
print(res)

#     C1  C2
# 1  1.0 NaN
# 4  NaN NaN
```